# Error in my shell script : below code is giving error in my shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, concurrency, interface

```
set $PARAM; shift; shift; shift; shift; shift; shift; shift; shift
PARAM=`echo $* | tr '"' '#' | sed 's/# #/#/g'`

PARAM_LST=`get_params`

split_params $PARAM_LST
```

I am not sure what above piece of code does, but these lines of code giving me error while running my shell script

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: I am it running from conc. program of oracle apps   /u01/oracle/app/fs1/EBSapps/appl/xxcustom/12.0.0/bin/XXCUSTOM_PO_BULK_RECEIPTS_UPLOAD
Program exited with status 1